# How to add an event listener on the button of DrawingManagerControl?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I want to catch a `click` event on `Draw Polygon` button. But the DrawingManager API provides only `overlaycomplete` events (polygoncomplete, circlecomplete, etc). How may I add a `click` event on those buttons? Particularly I want to forbid to draw the second polygon if one polygon shape is already on the map. So I want add a `click` handler to `Draw Polygon` button and return negative response.

**UPD:**

So I did as follows:

```
onDrawingmode_changedListener = google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'drawingmode_changed', function(e) {
   if(this.getDrawingMode() == "polygon") {
      if(polygon) {
         alert("You already have one polygon shape on the map. Remove it in order to draw a new one.");
         this.setDrawingMode(null);
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no implemented way to access these controls. you have 2 options:

1. observe the `drawingmode_changed`-event of the DrawingManager-instance. When the `drawingmode` is set to `google.maps.drawing.POLYGON`, set it to `null` (it will no longer be possible to draw a polygon)
2. update `drawingManager.drawingControlOptions.drawingModes` . Set it to an array that contains all overlay-types except `google.maps.drawing.POLYGON` (this will remove the POLYGON-control ) . Here also set the `drawingmode` to `null`

---

Explanation of the `drawingmode`_changed-event:

An DrawingManager-instance is an [MVCObject](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#MVCObject). MVCObjects have build-in property-setters(`set()` and `setValues()`). The Maps-API uses these setters to set properties. Each time you use these methods an event will be triggered with a name that conist of the property-name and the string `_changed` (e.g. when you set a property `weather` of an `MVCObject` via the setter, an event `weather_changed` will fire). This also happens when you use the specific setter-functions( setZoom, setCenter, setMap etc.).

So you may assume that for each property of an MVCObject the `_changed`-event will fire as long as the setters will be used(applies to built-in properties and custom properties ), no matter if the event is documented or not.

Example:

```
        google.maps.event.addListener(map,'weather_changed',function(){
          alert('it\'s '+this.get('weather'));
        });
         //this will fire a weather_changed-event
        map.set('weather','rainy');
         //this will not fire an event, because it doesn't use a setter-method
        map.weather='rainy';
```

Comment: Great solution. I have chosen the first one and it works perfectly, just as I need. Thank you. A little remark: the API reference page (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl) doesn't have `drawingmode_changed` event. But nevertheless the event exists.

Comment: See above for an  explanation of the origin of the undocumented event.